# ¿Transaccion SQL Server insertar lista de objetos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transacciones

Quisiera me orientaran, tengo en una transacción un procedimiento almacenado que realiza lo siguiente:

La tabla Ventas tiene un trigger que se dispara cuando la columna "ProductoId" es cambiada, esto para registrar los cambios hechos en la tabla "Ventas" en una bitácora

Mi problema: Se genera un timeOut por default tenia 30 seg, lo he cambiado a 2000 seg que son aproximadamente 33.3 min. pero se acaba el tiempo y manda la exepcion del timeout, ¿Puedo optimizar mi procedimiento para no tener ese problema? tengo entendido que una vez que se inicia la transaccion las tablas se bloquean, necesito consejos para completar la transaccion.

```
    UPDATE dbo.Cliente
    SET ProductoID= @ProductoNuevoID,
    WHERE ClienteID= @ClienteID;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ClienteProductoBitacora
    (
        ClienteID,
        ProductoAnterioID,
        ProductoCambioID,
        FechaCreacion,
        UsuarioCreacion,
        UsuarioDominioCreacion
    )
    VALUES
    (   
        @ClienteID,
        @ProductoAnterioID,
        @ProductoCambioID,
        GETDATE(), -- FechaCreacion - datetime
        User_Name(),        -- UsuarioCreacion - varchar(50)
        @Usuario         -- UsuarioDominioCreacion - varchar(50)
    )


    UPDATE dbo.Ventas
    SET ProductoID= @ProductoCambioID
    WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID;

    END
    GO
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código que va dentro de la transacción?

Comment: No entiendo el último `update` ¿Es correcto modificar todos los `Id` de productos de un Cliente?

Comment: Puedes crear indices ayudan a mejorar los tiempos de ejecución en las consultas.